# How to write serial data to COM ports with Universal Windows Application?

Tags: c#, serial-port, win-universal-app, serial-communication

Typically C# applications use `System.IO.Ports` like so:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1"); 
port.Open(); 
port.WriteLine("test");`
```

But Universal Windows Applications don't support `System.IO.Ports` so this method cannot be used. Does anyone know how to write serial data through COM ports in a UWA?

Comment: At least look at [the sample](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/SerialSample.htm), you can't possibly miss DataWriter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with the [Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.serialcommunication.aspx) and [Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br208154) classes:

> The classes provide functionality to discover such serial device, **read and write data**, and control serial-specific properties for flow control, such as setting baud rate, signal states.

By adding the following capability to `Package.appxmanifest`:

```
<Capabilities>
  <DeviceCapability Name="serialcommunication">
    <Device Id="any">
      <Function Type="name:serialPort" />
    </Device>
  </DeviceCapability>
</Capabilities>
```

Then running the following code:

```
using Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

//...   

string selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM3"); 
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
if(devices.Count > 0)
{
    DeviceInformation deviceInfo = devices[0];
    SerialDevice serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
    serialDevice.BaudRate = 9600;
    serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
    serialDevice.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.Two;
    serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;

    DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(serialDevice.OutputStream);
    dataWriter.WriteString("your message here");
    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
    dataWriter.DetachStream();
    dataWriter = null;
}
else
{
    MessageDialog popup = new MessageDialog("Sorry, no device found.");
    await popup.ShowAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has provided an example of accessing and using a com port, using the class SerialDevice, in a Universal Windows Application, named CustomSerialDeviceAccess.

Microsoft has posted it on GitHub. You can find it here:

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomSerialDeviceAccess

Microsoft says this about the sample application:

> "This sample allows the user to configure and communicate with a Serial
>   device. You can choose one of four scenarios:
>
> Connect/Disconnect using Device Selection list; Configure the Serial
>   device; Communicate with the Serial device; Register for Events on the
>   Serial device"

References:  Microsoft, GitHub